# Isotope and prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery-isotope, prettyphoto

Has anyone managed to get prettyPhoto to work along with Isotope?

I have got it integrated - however when I filter using isotope to view a particular set of images, I still get the full set of images in prettyPhoto.

You can see the page on my test site: http://wordpress.markrichardson.co.uk/wedding-photography-gallery/

The code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){ var $container = $('#wedding');
    $checkboxes = $('#filters input'); $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var filters = [];
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
          filters.push( this.value );
        });
        filters = filters.join(', ');
        $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
    });
    $container.isotope({
        // options
    itemSelector : '.photo',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows', 
    sortBy : 'random',
    sortAscending : true
     });
    }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("a[rel^='[wedding_photography]']").prettyPhoto({
    slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
                opacity: 0.70,
                show_title: false,
                allow_resize: false,
                default_width: 950,
                default_height: 500,
                theme: 'light_rounded', 
                horizontal_padding: 20,
    overlay_gallery: false,
                social_tools: false,
    deeplinking: false
    });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you solved this yet, but I can share how I approached this task by integrating isotope with shadowbox.js.  I was looking for the same functionality as you described, but used a different tool to get there.  First, I downloaded the css and js code from the shadowbox website and put them in my folder.  Then I added the following code to the header element of my html document:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, in the HTML, I added this to the images to get them to appear inside the shadowbox.  [niceboxes] is the gallery name and all images with this tag get put into the same gallery:

```
<div class="box brown square">
   <h2 class="box-title">Deluxe Brown Box</h2>
   <div class="box-img">
   <a href="brown_box.jpg" rel="shadowbox[niceboxes]" title="brown box"><img src="brown_box_thumbnail.png"/></a>  
 </div>
</div>
```